# Handling checkboxlist inside Repeater control using asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, repeater

After binding the repeater control, my check box looks like the below,

I have two doubts here:

1. If I select checkbox of Group 1, all the items under group 1 should be selected. How can I do this ?
2. And I have "Select ALL" button which when clicked should select all the items of all groups. Since the checkbox is inside the repeater control, I'm not sure how to handle it.

```
  Group 1
       Item 1
       Item 2

    Group 2
       Item 3
       Item 4

    Group 3
       Item 5 
       Item 6




  ASPX : 

    <ol>
        <asp:Repeater ID="rp_Groups" runat="server" OnItemDataBound="rp_Groups_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <ul>
                    <asp:CheckBox RepeatColumns="2" runat="server" ID="chk_Group" Text='<%# Eval("category_type") %>' Value='<%# Eval("service_type_category_id") %>' onclick="OnGroupClick" />

                     <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="chkServiceType" style="padding-left:20px" DataValueField="ServiceTypeID" DataTextField="Name" EnableViewState="true"
                     ></asp:CheckBoxList>

                  <br />
                </ul>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ol>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function OnGroupClick(group) { 
  for(item in group.getElementsByTagName('input')) {
     item.checked = group.checked;
  }
}

   function selectAll() {
        $("#<%=chkServiceType.ClientID %> input[type=checkbox]").each(function () {
            this.checked = true;
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: not sure but: onclick for ASP objects means Server-Side... try onclientclick...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the checkbox onclick event from repeater Itemdatabound event as follow to call JavaScript function.

```
protected void rp_Groups_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
         try
        {
            System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox chk =  (System.Web.UI.WebControls.CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("chk_Group");

            chk.Attributes.Add("onclick", "selectGroupAll("+chk.ClientID+");");
        }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {

         }

    }
```

Then you need to write function in JavaScript

1) Function to select the group checkbox (I am passing the client id of the checkbox group from the page behind. Now I am finding the all the check box which belong to one group and make them checked true.)

```
function selectGroupAll(chk) {         


            $(chk).parent().parent().find(":checkbox").attr("checked", true);

        }
```

2) Select ALL on Button Click

Write function in JavaScript and call it from button click event

```
function selectAll() {

            $(':checkbox').each(function () {
                this.checked = true;
            });
        }
```

Button form calling the function

```
 <input type="button" value="Test" onclick="selectAll();" />
```